# Learners of English SE site?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

What Stack Exchange site should I use to learn English to an advanced level?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You probably want [**English Language Learners**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) if you’re learning English as a second language:

> English Language Learners Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for speakers of other languages learning English.

If you’re a native speaker, and looking to dive into advanced aspects of the English language, then [**English Language & Usage**](http://english.stackexchange.com) sounds more appropriate:

> English Language & Usage Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.

There are questions spread across the various Metas about whether a question should be asked on ELL or EL&U:

- [How do I determine whether a question fits on English Language & Usage or on English Language Learners?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14)
- [Drawing the lines between ELL and EL&U](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7945)

Note that, of course, you should only use these sites for asking questions about English and/or difficulties you’re having while learning. Don’t expect tutorials or teachers – that’s not what Stack Exchange is for.